# Unable to use other configurations than Debug and Release in MAUI

Tags: maui

I want more configuration like UAT, Pre-Prod but I can only run Debug.

I have added more configuration from project settings:

[image]

If I run other configuration, I am getting `Selected exexution mode is not supported for .Net Projects` error.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I found a solution. And I posted the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. So basically other configuration works in **Visual Studio 2022(Windows)** but gets an error in **Visual Studio for MAC 2022** [Issue Link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8894#issuecomment-1210331944).

Until **Visual Studio For MAC** solves this issue we can run different configurations using the terminal using the commands link:

**Command:** `dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=:v2:udid=MY_SPECIFIC_UDID -c <Configuration>`

**ex:** `dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=:v2:udid=2B4C2D4C-18E2-4C5F-8A38-51CE611A1899 -c UAT`

we can skip the DeviceName part. Which will run the app in the default simulator.
**Command:** `dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-ios -c UAT`

Comment: thanks for the workaround. Do you know how to attach the debugger in VS for Mac to the app running on the simulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

It provides two configuration options Debug and Release for the Maui. This is why you choose the other configurations it appears the error that `Selected exexution mode is not supported for .Net Projects`.

For more information you can refer to [the Deployment for iOS platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/?view=net-maui-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround from @Monil Gandhi, about using the CLI to run the build, does work.
However it makes it difficult to debug a UAT build as the VS for Mac debugger doesn't attach automatically if you use the CLI.

#### If you want to use the debugger with iOS

1. Create your custom configurations, *and do not delete the Debug*.
2. Update your most commonly used configuration condition to be used by the debug build as well.
3. If you need to debug another configuration, you can move the Debug predicate portion of your conditional statement to the configuration you want to debug.

Example: If you had the configuration below

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp - Debug</ApplicationTitle>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'UAT|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp - UAT</ApplicationTitle>
    <DefineConstants>UAT</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'PROD|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp</ApplicationTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and you wanted to debug UAT, you can update 'Debug' to use the UAT values. Be sure to comment out any Debug configurations that would conflict with your UAT configuration.

```xml
<!-- <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp - Debug</ApplicationTitle>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup> -->
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' OR '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'UAT|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp - UAT</ApplicationTitle>
    <DefineConstants>UAT</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'PROD|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>MyApp</ApplicationTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```